# Is there an easy way to expand a Linux VMs disk?

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, hard-drive, storage, cloud

Im currently planning a cloud solution.
The cloud is supposed to run on Linux VMs via vSphere.
Right now, every time I want to increase the virtual disk space of an already set up Linux VM, it’s a hassle because I‘m using the gparted iso, which means I have to shut down each VM to expand the disk and then do some extra work once I’ve increased the disk to get the file system to recognize it.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Using LVM makes it really easy to resize the disks on the fly. But most important is to place the partition that is going to be resized at the end of the disk during installation.

For example, traditionally swap partitions are placed are the end of the disk. For VMs it's better to place them at the start and the root partition at the end, so you only need to do the resize and don't have to move the swap partition first.

Answer (score 0):

Attach an additional LUN for data. Do not partition it. Create a data VG and use the entire disk as PV. For example,  `vgcreate data /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x600224808c29a2f7c33002b425d6da86`

Skipping the partition is not a popular thing to do, some people and tools assume partitions. But Linux LVM does not need them.

With guest drivers, expanding the LUN will appear immediately to the kernel. `pvresize` will give the new space to LVM.  `lvresize --resizefs`  will extend the LV online, and also resize some common file systems.